# Does this writing style have a proper name?

Tags: academic-writing

I'm curious to know if this style of writing (pattern) has a name. They can sometimes take up almost a full paragraph giving background about a specific person or subject when introducing them into an article.

"At the Saturday briefing, Dr. Stephen Hahn, commissioner of the Food and Drug Administration, co-author of the critically claimed book "XYZ", told us that..."

Comment: Maybe "journalism"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In news writing, it might be called an attribution or background clause or sentence. Reporters *attribute* a fact or description to a source; that is, they identify a person, publication, document as the source of the information. Those sentences often include background or identifying information, as in the question. I don't believe most reporters have a formal name for that -- a string of non-restrictive clauses with biographical information after referring to a person or source.

Comment: Thank you! I'm building a pattern recognizer and this is one that kept coming up, but I didn't have a label for it. I'll ask it in journalism, but attribution seems right so far.